# How to print pcl or esc/p code on host-driven printer?

Tags: printing, pdf, cups

I have a host-based printer (HP Deskjet D2460) and have some printer language files (pcl codes) that I would like to print out. I saw that in cups there are some filters like rastertopcl, etc. which converts a raster format, for cups that is postscript into pcl... How to do the inverse?

If it is not possible, how to convert pcl to ps or pdf? A good little executable or python/perl script (interested in free solutions)

Comment: Can't you just pipe the files, as is, to the printer, if all you want to do is "like to print out" the files?

Comment: I was thinking about `cat filename > /dev/yourprintersusb`

Comment: I see, but the printer does not understand PCL codes, so it can't print it by himself. It does not work if I give it lp -o raw filename.

Comment: I did not check against the version, I assumed that it being an HP printer it would understand about HP's PCL language. I don't know about any free pcl2pdf convertors for Linux, but if this is a one-off and you access to a Windows box, you could at [PCLReader](http://www.filetransit.com/download.php?id=33952)

Comment: Seems there is something for Linux as well: [openpcl](http://sourceforge.net/projects/openpcl/), unfortunately it is in Java

Comment: Tried to test it but the jar returned an exception: The Microsoft Windows Look and Feel - com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsLookAndFeel] not supported on this platform. I'm testing on an Ubuntu 14.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recent versions of ghostscript include a pcl interpreter, and can work with the full range of ghostscript output formats including pdf, ps, image formats like Tiff and Jpeg, and all their known printers. You may need to compile from source. I have no Idea if this will work directly with your printer or if additional intermediate steps would be needed. As a worst case, since That printer will support printing photos from sd cards, you can place your images there after converting to a supported format, unplugging the usb cable and printing from the printer screen.

Comment: If I understand correctly the affero license the ghostscript is not free for all, it has to be bought if used in commercial application... Intrestingly I saw in Pdf Creator that they are using ghostscript and pdf creator is used in many commercial environments.

Comment: the affero license is a gpl3 variant, the Artifex Commercial License is a paid licence, both ghostscript and ghostpcl are available under each licence.

Comment: Thanks. To supplement this answer, the gpl3 variant can be used in commercial programs as it is stated here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2280742/gplv3-can-i-use-these-programs-in-commercial